# How to delete safari History, Cache, Cookies, Top sites, Saved state and local storage in cocoa app(Mac) in objective c

Tags: macos, cookies, safari, browser-cache, browser-history

I am new in cocoa app development. I want to delete programmatically safari History, Cache, Cookies, Top sites, Saved state and local storage once I quit safari in objective c.
Please help me if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete safari History, Cache, Cookies, Top sites, Saved state and local storage files for all browsers by searching these files location under path ~/Library/Application Support/ and then that browser folder name.

For Safari you will get all files under ~/Library path.

After went to that files folder location use NSFileManager to delete files.